# django 1.5 extend the default User model or substitute it

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-cms, django-users

Env: Django 1.5.1 + Django CMS 2.4.1 + Zinnia latest + my custom apps + custom Django CMS plugin

Basically I can extend the default Django (1.5.X) User model 
like [Django Ribbit Tutorial on NetTuts+](https://github.com/NETTUTS/django-ribbit/blob/master/ribbit_app/models.py)

or

Substitute a completely customized model like [Django Dev doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) or Django2Scoops example in the paragraph: "Dealing With the User Model"

To test I decided for Subclass AbstractUser
From Django2Scoops book:"Choose this option if you like Django’s User model fields the way they are, but need extra ..fields."

But I have the following errors:

> notification.noticesetting: 'user' defines a relation with the model
>   'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point
>   at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL. cmsplugin_zinnia.latestentriesplugin:
>   'authors' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has
>   been swapped out. Update the relation to point at
>   settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
>
> cms.pageuser: 'created_by' defines a relation with the model
>   'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point
>   at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL. cms.pageusergroup: 'created_by' defines a
>   relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
>   Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.

After hours of reading and test I found

[Specifying custom User model (extends AbstractUser) doesn't work](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/django-users/VwLF8G3IBC4)

> As the error message says -- you need to update the relation to point
>   at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL. The second error ("Model has been swapped
>   out…") is a side effect of the fact that you're directly referencing
>   the User model. Once you change the ForieignKey references, this third
>   error will go away. We've done everything we can to ensure a smooth
>   transition to the new User model, but it can't be completely
>   transparent. App writers will need to update their apps to be 1.5
>   compatible. Essentially, a Django 1.4 app won't be 100% compatible
>   with Django 1.5 if it contains a hard-coded foreign key reference to
>   User.  Please, could you give me more examples?

And [Django/Python: Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215976/django-python-update-the-relation-to-point-at-settings-auth-user-model)

> in settings_example.py you have AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'.
>   However you are using an app - menu.bookmark - that has a relation to
>   django.contrib.auth.User - you can't have both. Setting
>   AUTH_USER_MODEL means that you are replacing the built-in Django user
>   model with your own. See
>   http://procrastinatingdev.com/django/using-configurable-user-models-in-django-1-5/
>   for details.

But I don't understand how can I solve this.

What I would need:

-Users are linked to Institutes Class (one institute -> more users)

-Users or Institutes can have different permission and see different django cms 
pages/plugin.

-Several more fields for User.

Is Subclass AbstractUser the correct point?

How can I solve the "swapped out" error?

I should create something similar to [OpenTreeMap Code](https://github.com/azavea/OpenTreeMap/blob/v1.3/profiles/models.py)

Isn't deprecated this code?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1798 django CMS does not support AUTH_USER_MODEL at the moment. Hence what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is very simple solution. Just need to register your custom user before importing CMSPlugin. Example:

> ```
> from django.db import models
> from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models
> from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
>
> class User(AbstractUser):
>   telephone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>   email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>
> auth_models.User = User
>
> from cms.models import CMSPlugin
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my summary of the further discussion at https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1798.

There are four potential options:

1. If you need your custom user model to have a name other than User, you'll need to wait.
2. You can call the custom user model `User` - though when I tried this, I got errors about clashes with related m2m fields. There are some further details on the above link which may help resolve this.
3. Django 1.5 still lets you use user profiles. So if you are ok with using a deprecated feature, you can still use Django-CMS 2.4 and Django 1.5 with user profiles instead of a custom user model. (I misread the Django docs here and thought user profiles were not supported in Django 1.5.)
4. You can often get away without either a user profile or a custom user model - they are best used to add data specifically for user authentication. Instead, you can use another model with a one-to-one relationship to `User`, and use the reverse relationship to access it.

For my case, I am going to go with #3 in the short-run and #4 in the long-run.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Racing Tadpole! As you I am going to go with #3 and #4 in the long-run. The doc was not so clear + Dajngo2Scoops book says "Option 3: Subclass AbstractBaseUser": AbstractBaseUser is the bare-bones option with: password, last login, and is active.

1)
You’re unhappy with the fields that the User model provides by default, such as first name and last name.


2)
You prefer to subclass from an extremely bare-bones clean slate but want to take advantage of the AbstractBaseUser sane default approach to storing passwords.